# Why Oracle LOCK Table when using INNER SELECT from this Table on UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency, locking, consistency

As we know by official  [Oracle Data Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm)
*A reader never blocks a writer*

But I surprised on my Oracle application
Following `Inner SELECT` statement (from `PERSON` Table)

```
UPDATE MANAGER m
SET 
m.manager_name  =
    (
        SELECT p.person_name
        FROM PERSON p
        WHERE p.person_code = (m.manager_code)
    )
;
```

**Lock any another (UPDATE or INSERT) statements on PERSON Table**
Until above `UPDATE` `MANAGER` statement committed or rollbacked

Any Help why?
And how to know what is the type of LOCK obtained in this case?

Comment: `A reader never blocks a writer` - that phrase means that SELECT statement (reader) never blocks a writer (INSERT+UPDATE+DELETE statements). There are no any readers in the question though (I can't see SELECT statement there), but there are two writers (update+insert). In this case this phrase is not true, writers sometimes block each other.

Comment: What makes you think PERSON is locked?

Comment: @BobC when try to INSERT/UPDATE any record of PERSON ... session waits until UPDATE MANAGER statement finished (committed or rollbacked)

Comment: @YajliMaclo What indexs and constraints do you have on the two tables?

Comment: Are these tables linked by foreign key ?

Comment: @krokodilko YES .. MANAGER.person_id = PERSON.id

Comment: @YajliMaclo. Presumable MANAGER is the parent and PERSON is the child? What is the database version?

Comment: is it possible that these tables are in a cluster? i.e. they share the segment?